# Attach image to a recorded audio file?

Tags: objective-c

After I have recorded audio and stored it in a file using the AVAudioRecorder, I email it to the user from from the app. It's working fine.

Now, however, I need to take an image that I have in my app and attach it to the video, and then send it via email, so when the video is playing you will see that image in the player.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

I send the email like this:

```
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"your email"];
    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    NSString *sound=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sound%d.caf",[memoryInstnace getLastRecordSoundNumber]];

    NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *dataPath = [[paths2 objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:sound];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
    [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"caf" fileName:sound];//
```

Comment: Well, first off, you're emailing a soundfile (.caf). If I get your question, you want an image to display in the video feed when something like QuickTime plays the file, right? Well, I don't think you can't use .caf for that, as it can't encapsulate video.

Comment: ok i got it . thanks. if i will use mp3, will it be possible ?